# Why different Users for different services - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i am preparing for Microsoft exam 70-432 SQL Server 2008 . In the book i read, its highly recommended that you use separate log-in for each SQL Service. But i am unable to understand what is a benefit in using separate USER?

Please let me know if anyone has an idea about this.

Regards, 
fayalif

Answer (score 0):

The benefit is that if somehow someone manages to take control of one of the services he will not have access to the other ones.

Comment: Furthermore, using a separate user for each service allows a more fine-grained specification of access writes.

Answer (score 0):

What Giorgi said *and* that the different services require different rights.

By using different accounts these individual accounts have as little rights as possible. Combining these accounts by using one account a malicious user could obtain enough rights to do damage.